# ASP.NET MVC Routing based on domain & hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, subdomain

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, most of my experience is on ASP.NET Webforms.

Is there a way to setup routing based on domain/hostname, i.e. www.domain.com goes to one area, admin.domain.com to another and www.differentdomain.com to yet another area all on the web application.

Also, is there a way to do a catch-all i.e. *.domain.com will be routed to another area?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use Domain Routing mapping

```html
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
    "{customer}.example.com", // Domain with parameters 
    "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
))
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!! [domain routing with asp.net mvc](http://wiki.terrasynq.net/tutorials/domain-routes-and-using-subdomains-in-mvc-as-routes/) makes this very clear.

Comment: The link to domain routing is broken.

Comment: Since the link is broken, this answer has the implementation details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28669469/87453

Comment: Is there a way to do this with route attribute?