# Domain Routing in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I realize there are a few articles on similar things but none of which has helped me.

I have a single web app with multiple domains pointing to the same app. I would like to know how I can map a route to a specific controller based on the domain that is trying to access the web app.

What I currently tried is the following with no success.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WowPoetry",
    url: "wowpoetry.org/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Wow", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I ended up following this tutorial to achieve what I wanted to with the exception of I used to to do domain routing and not subdomain routing.

[Domain Routing Tutorial ASP.Net MVC](http://wiki.terrasynq.net/tutorials/domain-routes-and-using-subdomains-in-mvc-as-routes/)

Implementation:

```cs
routes.Add(new DomainRoute("wowpoetry.org", "", new { controller = "Wow", action = "Index" }));
```

DomainData.cs

```cs
public class DomainData
{
    public string Protocol { get; set; }
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string Fragment { get; set; }
}
```

DomainRoute.cs

```cs
public class DomainRoute : Route
{
    private Regex domainRegex;
    private Regex pathRegex;

    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults)
        : base(url, defaults, new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Domain = domain;
    }

    public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, defaults, routeHandler)
    {
        Domain = domain;
    }

    public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Domain = domain;
    }

    public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
        : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), routeHandler)
    {
        Domain = domain;
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Build regex
        domainRegex = CreateRegex(Domain);
        pathRegex = CreateRegex(Url);

        // Request information
        string requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Headers["host"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestDomain))
        {
            if (requestDomain.IndexOf(":") > 0)
            {
                requestDomain = requestDomain.Substring(0, requestDomain.IndexOf(":"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
        }
        string requestPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) +
                             httpContext.Request.PathInfo;

        // Match domain and route
        Match domainMatch = domainRegex.Match(requestDomain);
        Match pathMatch = pathRegex.Match(requestPath);

        // Route data
        RouteData data = null;
        if (domainMatch.Success && pathMatch.Success && requestDomain.ToLower() != "tg.local" &&
            requestDomain.ToLower() != "tg.terrasynq.net" && requestDomain.ToLower() != "www.townsgossip.com" &&
            requestDomain.ToLower() != "townsgossip.com")
        {
            data = new RouteData(this, RouteHandler);

            // Add defaults first
            if (Defaults != null)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Defaults)
                {
                    data.Values[item.Key] = item.Value;
                }
            }

            // Iterate matching domain groups
            for (int i = 1; i < domainMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Group group = domainMatch.Groups[i];
                if (group.Success)
                {
                    string key = domainRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                        {
                            data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Iterate matching path groups
            for (int i = 1; i < pathMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Group group = pathMatch.Groups[i];
                if (group.Success)
                {
                    string key = pathRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                        {
                            data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, RemoveDomainTokens(values));
    }

    public DomainData GetDomainData(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        // Build hostname
        string hostname = Domain;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
        {
            hostname = hostname.Replace("{" + pair.Key + "}", pair.Value.ToString());
        }

        // Return domain data
        return new DomainData
        {
            Protocol = "http",
            HostName = hostname,
            Fragment = ""
        };
    }

    private Regex CreateRegex(string source)
    {
        // Perform replacements
        source = source.Replace("/", @"\/?");
        source = source.Replace(".", @"\.?");
        source = source.Replace("-", @"\-?");
        source = source.Replace("{", @"(?<");
        source = source.Replace("}", @">([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*))");

        return new Regex("^" + source + "$");
    }

    private RouteValueDictionary RemoveDomainTokens(RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        var tokenRegex =
            new Regex(
                @"({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?");
        Match tokenMatch = tokenRegex.Match(Domain);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokenMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            Group group = tokenMatch.Groups[i];
            if (group.Success)
            {
                string key = group.Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
                if (values.ContainsKey(key))
                    values.Remove(key);
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: Found any way of subdomain Routing?

Comment: It works with regular ASP.NET MVC 5, Thanks for sharing ☺