# ASP MVC \ Subdomains on Localhost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm testing a ASP MVC EF application.. with IIS Express locally. I'm trying to determine the subdomain in the HTTP request but I receive a "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" error

I've looked at some of the answers about changing the host file but that did not resolve the error.

In my HomeController I have this method to simply print the requesting URL

> public string Index() { var hn = Request.Headers["HOST"]; return
>   hn.ToString(); }

when viewing localhost -> the page loads

when viewing tenant1.localhost -> Bad Request

Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction to resolve this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Invalid hostname is a "dns" issue - that's why you need to create entries in your `hosts` file for any/all "local" "subdomain" you want to resolve. It's assumed you have an entry for `tenant1.localhost` in your `hosts` file for that to work (also assumed that IIS is setup properly once you get `hosts` file done - likely via host header setup). You'll need to do this in IIS manager.

Comment: hey, yea i did this:

    127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.0.1       tenant1.localhost

Answer (score 0):

By default, IIS Express only allows `localhost`. In order to allow another domain to hit your site in development, you must manually add a binding in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`. Find the `<site>` node that corresponds with your application and in the `<bindings>` node, add a new `<binding>`. There will be the default binding there to use as a guide. Don't mess with the default binding, though, or you can end up with strange errors in Visual Studio.

Additionally, I would recommend using something like [localtest.me](http://readme.localtest.me/) to test subdomains, as the `subdomain.localhost` construct doesn't tend to work well, since most things will try to assume that `localhost` is the tld. Basically, localtest.me is a domain that has been set up to wildcard route everything to 127.0.0.1 (localhost). So you can pick and use whatever subdomain you want. For what it's worth, this is also very effective for testing third-party integrations like Facebook in development, since they don't allow localhost.

Comment: Hello Chris, I find nothing in my applicationhost.config under site. do you means the one that is inside my .vs folder. Maybe new convention are storing the settings inside .vs folder. I read it another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `Paul Taylor` answer above is pretty good but that didn't work entirely for me.
I use this implementation of `Route` class.

**Add your custom domain into `C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` file**

- 127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost.com

`DomainData.cs`

```
public class DomainData
{
  public string Protocol { get; set; }
  public string HostName { get; set; }
  public string Fragment { get; set; }
}
```

`DomainRoute.cs`

```
public class DomainRoute : Route
{
  private Regex domainRegex;
  private Regex pathRegex;

  public string Domain { get; set; }

  public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults)
    : base(url, defaults, new MvcRouteHandler())
{
    Domain = domain;
}

public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, RouteValueDictionary defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
    : base(url, defaults, routeHandler)
{
    Domain = domain;
}

public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults)
    : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new MvcRouteHandler())
{
    Domain = domain;
}

public DomainRoute(string domain, string url, object defaults, IRouteHandler routeHandler)
    : base(url, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), routeHandler)
{
    Domain = domain;
}

public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    // Build regex
    domainRegex = CreateRegex(Domain);
    pathRegex = CreateRegex(Url);

    // Request information
    string requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Headers["host"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestDomain))
    {
        if (requestDomain.IndexOf(":") > 0)
        {
            requestDomain = requestDomain.Substring(0, requestDomain.IndexOf(":"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        requestDomain = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
    }
    string requestPath = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) +
                         httpContext.Request.PathInfo;

    // Match domain and route
    Match domainMatch = domainRegex.Match(requestDomain);
    Match pathMatch = pathRegex.Match(requestPath);

    // Route data
    RouteData data = null;
    if (domainMatch.Success && pathMatch.Success && requestDomain.ToLower() != "tg.local" &&
        requestDomain.ToLower() != "tg.terrasynq.net" && requestDomain.ToLower() != "www.townsgossip.com" &&
        requestDomain.ToLower() != "townsgossip.com")
    {
        data = new RouteData(this, RouteHandler);

        // Add defaults first
        if (Defaults != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in Defaults)
            {
                data.Values[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }
        }

        // Iterate matching domain groups
        for (int i = 1; i < domainMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            Group group = domainMatch.Groups[i];
            if (group.Success)
            {
                string key = domainRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                    {
                        data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Iterate matching path groups
        for (int i = 1; i < pathMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            Group group = pathMatch.Groups[i];
            if (group.Success)
            {
                string key = pathRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !char.IsNumber(key, 0))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group.Value))
                    {
                        data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return data;
}

public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, RemoveDomainTokens(values));
}

public DomainData GetDomainData(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    // Build hostname
    string hostname = Domain;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in values)
    {
        hostname = hostname.Replace("{" + pair.Key + "}", pair.Value.ToString());
    }

    // Return domain data
    return new DomainData
    {
        Protocol = "http",
        HostName = hostname,
        Fragment = ""
    };
}

private Regex CreateRegex(string source)
{
    // Perform replacements
    source = source.Replace("/", @"\/?");
    source = source.Replace(".", @"\.?");
    source = source.Replace("-", @"\-?");
    source = source.Replace("{", @"(?<");
    source = source.Replace("}", @">([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*))");

    return new Regex("^" + source + "$");
}

private RouteValueDictionary RemoveDomainTokens(RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    var tokenRegex =
        new Regex(
            @"({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?({[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*})*\.?\/?");
    Match tokenMatch = tokenRegex.Match(Domain);
    for (int i = 0; i < tokenMatch.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        Group group = tokenMatch.Groups[i];
        if (group.Success)
        {
            string key = group.Value.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
            if (values.ContainsKey(key))
                values.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    return values;
  }
}
```

Reference: [Domain Routing in MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644293/domain-routing-in-mvc5)