# Change application behaviour based on whole URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

This might sound like a strange one. I'm hoping to have two identical instances of an application behave differently based on the URL used to access them.

I have two instances of the app deployed on IIS, let's call their paths `dev.routeone` and `dev.routetwo`. Both instances point to the same source. Now, say I have two actions in my `MainController` in this project, `ActionOne` and `ActionTwo`, linking up to HTML views `viewone.cshtml` and `viewtwo.cshtml` respectively.

The routing configuration would be set up something like this (in `RegisterRoutes`):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ActionOne",
    url: "one",
    defaults: new { controller = "MainController", action = "ActionOne" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ActionTwo",
    url: "two",
    defaults: new { controller = "MainController", action = "ActionTwo" }
);
```

With this setup, both IIS instances behave identically:

```
http://dev.routeone/one -> ActionOne
http://dev.routeone/two -> ActionTwo

http://dev.routetwo/one -> ActionOne
http://dev.routetwo/two -> ActionTwo
```

I want to have a situation where, using the same source code, the URL would indicate which action is run when a route is entered. Specifically in this case, `dev.routeone` directing both routes to `ActionOne` and the opposite with `dev.routetwo`:

```
http://dev.routeone/one -> ActionOne
http://dev.routeone/two -> ActionOne

http://dev.routetwo/one -> ActionTwo
http://dev.routetwo/two -> ActionTwo
```

Or better still, direct appropriately without the configured routes:

```
http://dev.routeone/ -> ActionOne
http://dev.routetwo/ -> ActionTwo
```

I'm not sure if this is possible or advisable, but am open to any solutions. Is there a way to 'look back' over the URL which isn't controlled by the application and use that to determine behaviour?

Comment: You want multiple applications with different base paths but same relative ones ?

Comment: Basically, yes. Though the multiple applications have the same source code

Comment: Maybe this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644293/domain-routing-in-mvc5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as I knew the two URLs that were going to be accessing the site, I was able to do this (note the slightly different formatting, as I have since introduced an `ID` param to the actions):

```
var appID = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationID;

if (appID.Contains("routeone")
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ActionOne",
        url: "{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MainController", action = "ActionOne", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}

if (appID.Contains("routetwo")
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ActionTwo",
        url: "{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "MainController", action = "ActionTwo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This format is not dynamic but can be expanded out to deal with more cases of increasing complexity.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a website just specify the same physical path and use different host names on this screen:

[image]

Comment: You misunderstand. I have done this, to create the separate routes, but both applications behave identically. I am hoping to access the applications using different host names (as you've described) but I want them to perform different actions depending on which one is accessed without having to write two separate websites.