# Using ASP.NET MVC Routing Direct To directory based on incomiing URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have two physical directories on my IIS server

```
c:\domains\general.net\js1
c:\domains\general.net\js2
```

I want the URL coming in

```
  www.spec1.net\js to go to c:\domains\general.net\js1
  www.spec2.net\js to go to c:\domains\general.net\js2
```

This is for the purposes of multi-tenancy. Please go with what I'm asking and believe me this is what I need.  Thanks.

This is not the same question as asked here: [ASP.NET MVC Routing based on domain & hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010926/asp-net-mvc-routing-based-on-domain-hostname)

Comment: This might need configuring at the IIS server not ASP.NET