# Is it possible to have multiple sets of Routes based off of request header?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an application which I would like to deploy across multiple domains with different routing patterns.

For example the about page may be:

- http://www.domain1.com/my-about-page

But also

- http://www.domain2.com/about/page

Both of these would go to the "About" action of my "Home" controller, and I don't want it to be possible for a user to go to "domain1.com/about/page".

Is it possible in ASP.NET MVC to set up different sets of routing dependant on a particular variable, such as request headers?

For example I could then have the route attributes as:

```
[Route("my-about-page", 1)]
[Route("about/page", 2)]
public ActionResult About()
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010926/asp-net-mvc-routing-based-on-domain-hostname)

Answer (score 0):

If you [inherit `RouteBase`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn786418.aspx), you can build any routing scheme that you want, including routing based on headers or anything else in the current request context.

Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/IDisposable/77f11c6f7693f9d181bb) for an example of domain-based routing.