# Custom route in Asp.Net MVC using custom attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

Assuming that I have the following `ASP.NET` website:
`http://example.com`

I want to expose this `url`:

```
http://yourCompany.example.com/yourName
```

and I want it to route to

```
{myController}/{myAction}/{yourCompany}&{YourName}
```

Can I setup a route for this in my `RegisterRoutes` in `RouteConfig` class?

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010926/asp-net-mvc-routing-based-on-domain-hostname

Answer (score 0):

You will have to redirect from the `http://yourCompany.example.com/[0]` to `http://example.com/yourCompany/[0]` as the subdomains are treated as stand-alone domains.