# Two domains pointing at two controllers of one c# mvc web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I haven't found a clear answer to this on StackOverflow/elsewhere:

Let's say I have domain **abc.com**, pointing at my c# mvc web application - **myApp**

myApp consists of services (controllers): **serviceA**, **serviceB**

*Is there a way to point another domain - xyz.com - to serviceB of myApp ?*

**=> so, the desired situation would be:**

**requests from abc.com should be handled by myApp's serviceA**

**requests from xyz.com should be handled by myApp's serviceB**

**If there is such a possibility in .net mvc , what is the best practice?**

I know I can have 2 two application running for each domain but I want to avoid this at this moment.

Please redirect me if there is already q/a for this. (haven't found any)

Comment: A similair question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010926/asp-net-mvc-routing-based-on-domain-hostname Aside from that, are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core? If you are using Core, then have a look at Ocelot that lets you do routing like you mentioned. https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot (specifically: https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/routing.html#upstream-host)

Comment: Hi, Roel. I am using .net framework. StackOw. link you provided looks promising to me. I will give it a try. Thx !